# In Ubuntu 10.04, how can I add the "manager" webapp to a private tomcat6 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04

I created a tomcat6 instance using the `tomcat6-instance-create` command from the `tomcat6-user` package. However, there are no webapps by default, and I want to add the "manager" webapp to this instance. For the system-wide tomcat6, this would be installed by installing the `tomcat6-admin` package. Is there any way to do this in Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it installs the manager webapp into the directory:

/usr/share/tomcat6-admin

I would expect you need to install the tomcat6-admin package first.

Comment: I have tomcat6-admin installed ... makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just downloading the [tomcat6 tarball](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi), and copying the "manager" webapp to my own tomboy instance. But it seems like there must be a better way...